# Show $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is not field, if $m$ is not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the book "a classical introduction to modern number theory", on page 33, I found paragraph:

> If $m$ is not a prime, then $m = m_1m_2$, where $0<m_1,m_2 < m$. Thus $\overline{m_1} \neq \overline{0}, \overline{m_2} \neq\overline{0}$, but $\overline{m_1}\,\overline{m_2}=\overline{m_1m_2}=\overline{m}=\overline{0}$. Therefore $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is not field.

I quite not understand logic of this statement. If $\overline{m_1} \times \overline{m_2} = \overline{0}$, then one of them must me zero. From definition, both are nonzero numbers, that is contradiction. If this is the way of thoughts, than how it deduces that $\mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}$ is not field?

Comment: "If product is zero then one of them is zero" - this is only true in integral domains, and all fields are integral domains. So since we have nonzero elements with zero product, $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ is not an integral domain and hence not a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** As an example: If $m=2^2$ it follows $A:=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has non-trivial zero divisors: The element $0 \neq x:=\overline{2} \in A$ satisfies $x^2=\overline{4}=0mod 4$.

**Question:** "Is this by definition that field can't contain non-trivial zero divisors?"

**Answer:** If $A$ is a field, for any element $0\neq a$ there is an element $a^{-1}$ with $aa^{-1}=1$. If $a\neq 0$ is a zero divisor, there is a non-zero element $b$ with $ab=0$. It follows

$$b=1b=(a^{-1}a)b=a^{-1}(ab)=a^{-1}0=0.$$

Hence $b=0$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Is this by definition that field can't contain non-trivial zero divisors?

Comment: @NikaTvildiani yes because a zero divisor can't have an inverse:$ba=0,ac=1,0=bac=b$

Comment: So $\overline{m_1} \times \overline{m_2} = \overline{0}$, means that one of then is zero divisor. Therefore it can't be field.